# jQuery Autocomplete data

Tags: php, jquery

Currently implementing jQuery autocomplete, the data is being passed back from the php file and populating fields but the autocomplete dropdown doesn't have any text in it. You can select the entry

Picture: [image]

As if the text for the result isn't being passed back?

```
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, firstname, surname, department, email FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE :term');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $row_array['id'] =  $row['id'];
        $row_array['firstname'] =  $row['firstname'];
        $row_array['surname'] = $row['surname'];
        $row_array['email'] = $row['email'];
        $row_array['department'] = $row['department'];

        $return_arr[] = $row_array;

    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


/* Toss back results as json encoded array. */
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}

//jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".auto").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 1,
    datatype: 'json',
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#firstname').val(ui.item.firstname)
      $('#surname').val(ui.item.surname);
      $('#department').val(ui.item.department);
      $('#email').val(ui.item.email);
      $('#hidden').val(ui.item.id);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, in its simplest form, your JSON response can be and array of strings :

```
[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
```

It can also be an array of objects containing a label and a value to be displayed in the autocomplete fields, for example :

```
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

Actually, the structure of the datas you are returning cannot be handled by JQuery UI autocomplete plugin.

See the detailed documentation here : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Hope this helps.